# Arrow Functions Execution Context

Tags: javascript, arrow-functions, executioncontext

```js
fun() // **Arrow Function (fun) is called before function definition**

var fun = () => {

  console.log("xdssdyz");
}
```

// **How it predicts that fun is not a function , according to execution context and function hoisting .**

Comment: Doesn't matter that it's an arrow function; this is a prime example of why functions should be declared using the `function` keyword (unless they have to be arrow functions)

Comment: Does this answer your question? [var functionName = function() {} vs function functionName() {}](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/336859/var-functionname-function-vs-function-functionname)

Comment: There is no hoisting for variables.

Comment: "How it predicts that fun is not a function ," - quite the opposite, it is saying it doesn't know what `fun` is and thus invoking it with `fun()` is not defined. Move the `fun()` call to underneath the definition and it should work. The runtime parser isn't doing anything magical, this is just a standard case of declare before use.

Comment: @JaredFarrish _"Hoisting refers to the process whereby the interpreter appears to move the declaration of functions, **variables** or classes to the top of their scope, prior to execution of the code. ... Variable and class declarations are also hoisted, so they too can be referenced before they are declared. Note that doing so can lead to unexpected errors, and is not generally recommended. "_ https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Glossary/Hoisting

Comment: @jabaa Clarification: The variable is hoisted as declared but isn't set. It wouldn't make sense to hoist the entire expression.

Answer (score 2):

You're trying to call

> fun()

before the declaration of it.

Comment: I would say `declaration` instead of `initialization` here

Comment: yes, my bad there. :D

Answer (score 0):

With hoisting `var`, the `fun` variable will be `undefined` before the declaration, and you try to execute `undefined` as a `function`, that's why it gives an error `Uncaught TypeError: fun is not a function

Answer (score 0):

arrow function isn't hoisted in javascript. An arrow function is not actually a function: it is an expression of a function and expressions is not hoisted in javascript. Basically an anonymous function is kept in a variable of arrow function instead of  declaring it. That's why such thing happens. If you want your function to be hoisted, declare it with `function` keyword, that's how js understands it as a function